# reorder Divs with jQuery then submit using form post

Tags: php, jquery

I use jQuery to sort items and it works perfectly fine, but how do I submit the final order using DIVs with form action post?

I know how to do it with check boxes like this...

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["resortable-option"])){
       foreach($_POST["resortable-option"] as $item){
         echo $item."<br>";
       }
    }
 ?>
```

....

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
   <ol id="sortable">
   <li><label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="resortable-option[]" value="1">Option 1</label></li>
   <li><label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="resortable-option[]" value="2">Option 2</label></li>
   <li><label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="resortable-option[]" value="3">Option 3</label></li>
   <li><label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="resortable-option[]" value="4">Option 4</label></li></ol>
   <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

This works perfectly fine for checkboxes, but what if I just want to use regular DIV instead and just pass the innerText or innerHtml of the div?  For example if I had...

```
 <ol id="sortable">
   <li><label for=""><div name="resortable-option[]">Option 1</label></li>
   <li><label for=""><div name="resortable-option[]">Option 2</label></li>
   <li><label for=""><div name="resortable-option[]">Option 3</label></li>
   <li><label for=""><div name="resortable-option[]">Option 4</label></li></ol>
```

then when i hit submit it would submit them after they been reorderd so i can catch...

```
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Option 4
```

as the output echo with the order they been reordered to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know how is to assemble the form html behind the scenes and submit that way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        // I'll use this as a class selector and as the name for the form attr
        var inputName   =   'resortable-option';
        // Get all elements with the class
        var getFields   =   $('.'+inputName);
        // Start the form
        var post        =   ['<form action="/test.php" method="post">'];
        // Loop through the divs
        $.each(getFields,function(k,v) {
            // Create inputs
            post.push('<input name="'+inputName+'['+k+']" value="'+$(v).text()+'" />');
        });
        // Add an ending to the form
        post.push('</form>');
        // String the array together and submit
        $(post.join('')).submit();
    });
});
</script>

<ol id="sortable">
   <li><label for=""><div class="resortable-option">Option 1</div></label></li>
   <li><label for=""><div class="resortable-option">Option 2</div></label></li>
   <li><label for=""><div class="resortable-option">Option 3</div></label></li>
   <li><label for=""><div class="resortable-option">Option 4</div></label></li>
</ol>
<div id="submit">SUBMIT</div>
```